# Can we say “Turn the scooter away / outward / off”?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, adverbs, idiomatic-language

> [away](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/away_1?q=away): to a different place or in a different direction
>
> Go away!
>
> Put your toys away.
>
> The bright light made her look away.

Look at the picture below

[image]

Your child was riding a scooter and the scooter ended up facing the wall.

Is it natural to say **Turn it ‘away’** or **‘outward’** or **‘off’ so that you can continue to ride**"?

**Note**: As long as the scooter won't face the wall, that is fine. We might turn it at about 90 degrees (i.e, the scooter and the wall are now parallel), not necessary at about 180 degrees (i.e, the back of the scooter and the wall are facing each other).

I heard some native speakers [say this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-turn-away-and-turn-around-for-example-could-you-turn-away-to-let-me-look-at-your-back-or-could-you-turn-around-to-let-me-look-at-your-back):

> When it’s used intransitively, ‘to turn around’ means to turn either
>   180 degrees or a full 360 degrees, depending on the context—at least,
>   it does in North America. If we’re driving a car and realize we should
>   have gone in the other direction, for example, then we turn around,
>   meaning 180 degrees. Brits would probably say ‘turn round.’

Comment: *Can* you? Probably. *Should* you? Almost certainly not. Just say *turn it* ***around***.

Comment: @JasonBassford, Does "turn it around" mean "turn it at 180 degrees"? what if we just turn it at about 90 degrees (the scooter and the wall are now parallel)?

Comment: Try saying "Back up the scooter and turn it!".

Comment: To *turn around* almost always means *reverse your [its] facing*. (But we would almost never actually say *reverse your facing* in normal conversation.)

Comment: If the scooter is electric, you can probably "turn it off", but form the drawing it appears not to be. You normally "TURN SOMETHING OFF" if they are electrical appliances, e.g. "turn off the light", or "turn the light off"

Comment: "Don't crash/go into the wall" would be my suggestion, or "Move away from that wall" or "Turn right" etc.